# Insert different user data into a database table in jsp

Tags: database, jsp, upload

i have problem to insert other user's data into a table in database. It's only success inserted by first. after a second user key in his/her data, it's failed. i have code like this:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<tr height=20% >
<td colspan="1" ><img src="appbanner.png" width=100% height=20%></td>
        </tr>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
 <body bgcolor="#D8CEF6" height="150">
     <h1>Create Task : </h1>
    <form name="createMemo" method="post" action="memoback.jsp">
        <pre> 

        Your  Memo Number   : <input type ="text" name="number" size="30">
        Enter Memo Text     : <input type ="text" name="memotext" size="30" style="width:500px" style ="height:500px"><br>


        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create Memo" />
        <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" />
        </pre>


    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

at my back end , i use jsp also to insert my code:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Create Task Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        String memonumber = request.getParameter("number");
        String memotext = request.getParameter("memotext");
        //String duedate = request.getParameter("date");
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db";
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,"db","db");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO MEMO(memoid,memotext,uname) VALUES ('"+memonumber+"','"+memotext+"','"+session.getAttribute("susername")+"')";
        statement.executeUpdate(SQL);
        response.sendRedirect("Home.jsp");
        %>
        Table is created successfully.
        <%
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        %>

    </body>
</html>
```

In my database table, i have columns memoid, memotext and uname.

Comment: Does it throw any exception?

Comment: no, after i click "create Memo" button pass the value to back end, my browser return a blank page. And there is no any data be inserted when i check my database.

Comment: i can insert data in database by enter sql statement but i would like to let user add in themselves in system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*i can insert data in database by enter sql statement but i would like to let user add in themselves in system*

Presume that users are having permissions in database table for DML operations.

Although writing Java code in JSP is highly discouraged,  modify your try catch block as

```
try{
    .....
    .....
}
catch(SQLException ex){
    System.out.println("exception "+ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

Comment out  `response.sendRedirect("Home.jsp");` for the time being.

Comment: @Plopan, it's work. look like  i did not put the close();. I'm new in coding and will try to do it using servlet. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: @raymond_wmt  Not sure what might have resolved the issue unless you provide more information, but `close();` is a must when you are using `Connection` or `Statement`. Glad to know your problem has been resolved.